# How to access methods/variables from swapped custom view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've created a window that contains an NSSplitView in which case the right custom view has a view that I swap into at runtime. The custom view swapped in contains a NSTableView with data inside it. I have a search box in the main window of the application that I want to be able to constrain the rows of the table view with.

I have the code to do this and I know it works, but the code I have was tested with a search text box and table view that were on the same window scope. With the text search box now being in the main window and the table view being in a different custom view, I'm not sure how to get the text search box to call the relevant methods from the custom view's controller class, because I don't have direct access to these method anymore.

I'm sure this is a very beginner question, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is your table view fed: Bindings or a data source? Why are you swapping it in at run time instead of just having it in the split view in the nib? What's your controller layout: Who owns the split view, and who owns the table view, and who are the search field and the table view talking to?

Comment: I'm binding to and ArrayConroller. When I said "swapping at runtime" I may have worded it badly, but what I meant was that the right-most custom view of the NSSplitView will be swapped with different views depending on what the user is doing (kind of like the iTunes interface). So the initial view of the program happens to be an NSTableView populated with text. So the "table view" view inherits from NSViewController and is instantiated in the main window controller. The main window controller owns the split view and a MainContentViewController controller owns the table view.

Comment: (above continued) I should clarify the above, the MainContentViewController is refering to the controller that controls the table view, it is not the controller for the main window, which I happened to name MainWindowController. So, the search field talks to the MainWindowController and the table view talks to the MainContentViewController. My MainWindowController instantiates an instance of the MainContentViewController and swaps its view into the NSSplitView's right-most custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Have your main window controller pass the search query or filter predicate to a property of the content view controller.

You can give the main window controller a weak-referencing (`assign`) property that holds the current content view controller. Implement a custom setter that not only assigns to the backing instance variable, but also does the swap. That, any time it's time to do a swap, you simply say `self.currentContentViewController = viewControllerToSwapIn`, and when it's time to change the query/predicate, you pass it to `self.currentContentViewController.searchQuery` (having implemented the `searchQuery` property in the MainContentViewController class and made all your actual content-view controllers inherit from that class).